# How to nest alignments while give subnested equations independent numbering?

Tags: equations, align, mathtools

I am trying to get alignment environments to be nested appropriately inside each other. We see Eq. 2 (using `aligned`) nested sucessfully inside `alignat`.

[image]

Two shortcomings arise due to this

1. such equation should be divided into two independent equations instead of one
2. it clear that such equation is not really centered, but rather aligned with the one of the columns of the main environment `alignat`

One potential solution is to use `aligned` inside `\shortintertext`

[image]

Such solution works for centering aligning the contents of Eq. 2 independently of what is the main alignment environment. However, one issue might also be seen is equation numbering being shifted downwards. Numbering is also still the same for two equations

**My question is:** how to nest alignments as in the previous figure while also provide appropriate independent numbering for all equations

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
    A + B &= C & \quad gfd
    \\
        \begin{aligned}
            x^{2} + y^{2} &= r^{2}
        \\
            (x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} &= r^{2}
        \end{aligned}
    \\
    D + E &= F & \quad gdf
    \\
    G + H &= I & \quad gdf
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{3}
    A + B &= C & \quad gfd
    \\
    \shortintertext{\centering
        $
        \begin{aligned}
            x^{2} + y^{2} &= r^{2}
            \\
            (x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} &= r^{2}
        \end{aligned}
        $
        }
    \\
    D + E &= F & \quad gdf
    \\
    G + H &= I & \quad gdf
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack with `\intertext` which produces what you want. Note we have to increase the equation counter and add the tag by hand for the line after the hacked \intertext.

Unrelated: you have two alignment columns , so you have to use `alignat{2}`. This requires `3` ampersands. Also, needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`: the latter does it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    A + B &= C & \quad & gfd
    \\
 \shortintertext{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
 \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 x^{2} + y^{2} &= r^{2}
 \\
 (x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} &= r^{2}
\end{aligned} \end{equation}
\end{minipage}\vskip-0.5ex}
 D + E &= F & & gdf \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}
    \\
    G + H &= I & & gdf
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your help is much appreciated. However, one requirement is still missing (each equation in `aligned` must get independent numbering). This may require new environment be employed

Comment: It was not clear to me. Do you mean each equation uses a counter different from the main equation counter, or just each has to be numbered within this counter?

Comment: Each equation must be numbered within the main counter of equations